# Azure function - [Error] (Function) Executed Messages cannot be larger than 65536 bytes. but without queue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

My Function is running directly from a Logic App, the Function sits at the end and receives the message from the Logic App, sometimes this message can be very large. That's why I've avoided using a queue.

Unfortunately I'm having the same situation without the queue and I cannot find a documentation to understand if it's a Function limitation or if it's just because I'm using HTTP request as the trigger.

If I use a blob, will the Function give me the same error with the same data?

The function uses http trigger (as linked to the logic app) and the data passed (as string) can be very small or very large.

The data flows correctly from Logic app to the function, I can print the data in the function when arrives from the logic app but after that I get the error

Comment: Is the Function using an `HttpTrigger`? How are you passing along the message? How big can the messages be? What is it you're trying to achieve? Please provide us with some more information. Also, please refer to [ask].

Comment: Hello @rickvdbosch, thank you for your reply.
The function is triggered with HttpTrigger as is the only available when attached to logic app.

The size of the message can be very small and sometimes very large depending the attachment of the email.

Comment: It really depends what form your message will take. Blob triggers are linked to a specific storage and will run the function when changes are brought to this storage, ie., if a new blob has been uploaded. Would that fit your needs ? More info here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp. Please also keep in mind that Azure Functions are not designed to process heavy workloads.

Comment: Hello @MarleneHE, thank you for your answer, I'm scared that I will have the same issue with bloob storage as the data is (apparently) correctly sent from the logic app to the function as I can print the data in the function but after the console.log I get that [error] message.

Is there any limit that azure function has on size of data?

Comment: To my knowledge it only applies to Queue messages, but it would be really helpful if you could post your code as well as your output if you want us to understand your issue.

Comment: just make it blob triggered and you're done